# T-SQL Problem

Tags: sql, t-sql, dd

I have following table (SQL Server) Table name is LandParcels

```
Blockid   ParcelNo  Stateorprivate
========================
11001901   30       Deemana
11001901   35       Deemana
11001901   41       State
11001901   45       State
11001901   110      Private
11001901   111      Private

11001902   1        Deemana
11001902   11       State
11001902   16       Private

11002001   15       Deemana
11002001   16       State
11003001   20       Private
11002003   2        Deemana
11002003   3        State
11003003   4        Private
```

Blockid (Numeric) = first 6 digits used for Cadastral Map No and last 2 digits for the Block No

eg: 110019 is Cadastal map no and 01 is Block No.

I used the following query

```
select substring(ltrim(str(blockid)),1,6) as blockid,stateorprivate, count(*) as noofLP from LandParcels group by blockid, stateorprivate order by blockid asc
```

Result is

```
Blockid  Stateorprivate  noofLP
========================
110019   Deemana         2
110019   State           2
110019   Private         2
110019   Deemana         1
110019   State           1
110019   Private         1
110020   Deemana         1
110020   State           1
110020   Private         1
110020   Deemana         1
110020   State           1
110020   Private         1
```

I want to get the following result for a report

```
blockid  noofBlocks   Deemana   State  Private  Amt_of_Deemana_State_Private
110019    2            3          3       3          9  
110020    2            2          2       2          6
```

How to query this. Pl help me.

Comment: Can you post the query you have tried to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(LTRIM(STR(Blockid)), 1, 6) AS blockid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(STR(Blockid)), 7, 2)) AS noofBlocks,
    SUM(CASE Stateorprivate WHEN 'Deemana' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Deemana,
    SUM(CASE Stateorprivate WHEN 'State' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [State],
    SUM(CASE Stateorprivate WHEN 'Private' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Private],
    SUM(CASE Stateorprivate
        WHEN 'Deemana' THEN 1
        WHEN 'State' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Private' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS Amt_of_Deemana_State_Private
FROM LandParcels
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(LTRIM(STR(Blockid)), 1, 6)
```

However, if the database schema is under your control, you should consider normalization.

Comment: Lot of Thanks Jacob. This is the real solution for me.
Lot of Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You start your query:

```
select substring(ltrim(str(blockid)),1,6) as blockid
```

which immediately gives the DB an ambiguity -- in the rest of the query, does `blockid` stand for the original column of that name, or does it stand for this homonymous one?

**don't do that** -- it's absurd to overload a DB engine with even more ambiguity than it already had to deal with; use `as myblockid` or whatever here, and `myblockid` in the rest of the query when **that** is what you mean. This may not solve every problem, but it will make your life, the DB engine's, AND that of anybody trying to help you out, much less of a nightmare.

Comment: Wasn't me, and I don't appreciate gratuitous down-votes for perfectly correct (if incomplete) answers either, especially as I'm struggling to see if I can break 10K tonight;-)

Comment: Just re-read the question which has been altered since I answered it, so it seems my answer wasn't correct, off to edit.  (also 10k it is)

Comment: The SQL standard lays down rules for how such possible ambiguities are to be handled; some DBMS deviate from the standard rules.

Comment: @Jonathan, yeah, unfortunately _most_ DBMS deviate from SQL standards in several ways -- including many one can't do much about, of course, but at least one can, and should, avoid ambiguity (which as I mentioned also makes life harder for humans reading the code and trying to help;-).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to check if this works, but you should look at using sum and case.

```
select
substring(ltrim(str(blockid)),1,6) as blockid,
sum(case stateorprivate when 'Deemana' then 1 else 0 end) as Deemana,
sum(case stateorprivate when 'State' then 1 else 0 end) as State,
sum(case stateorprivate when 'Private' then 1 else 0 end) as Private,
count(*) as Amt_of_Deemana_State_Private
from LandParcels group by blockid 
order by blockid asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) as blockid, 
    w.noofBlocks
    x.Deemana,
    y.State,
    z.Private,
    COUNT(*) AS Amt_of_Deemana_State_Private
FROM LandParcels lp
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) as myblockid, COUNT(*) AS Deemana
        FROM LandParcels lp2
        WHERE Stateorprivate = 'Deemana'
    ) x ON (substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) = x.myblockid)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) as myblockid, COUNT(*) AS State
        FROM LandParcels lp3
        WHERE Stateorprivate = 'State'
    ) y ON (substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) = y.myblockid)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) as myblockid, COUNT(*) AS Private
        FROM LandParcels lp4
        WHERE Stateorprivate = 'Private'
    ) z ON (substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) = z.myblockid)
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6) as myblockid)
        FROM LandParcels lp5
    ) w
GROUP BY substring(ltrim(str(lp.blockid)),1,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this query will achieve your desired results, except that the NoOfBlocks field is the first column instead of the second column. I also used CadastalMapNo for the result set column name instead of blockid on the suggestion from Alex Martelli that it added ambiguity because there was already something else named blockid. The reason that I put the NoOfBlocks field as the first column is because I believe that SQLServer requires the count function to be the first field in the select list when the distinct keyword is used.

I haven't actually tested this and it could have poor performance, but I'm pretty sure it's correct as I understand the question.

```
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(STR(blockid)),7,8)) as NoOfBlocks,
        SUBSTRING(LTRIM(STR(blockid)),1,6) as CadastalMapNo, 
        (CASE WHEN Stateorprivate='Deemana' then 1 else 0 end) as Deemana,
        (CASE WHEN Stateorprivate='State' then 1 else 0 end) as State,
        (CASE WHEN Stateorprivate='Private' then 1 else 0 end) as Private,
        COUNT(*) as Amt_of_Deemana_State_Private 
    FROM 
        LandParcels
    GROUP BY 
        CadastalMapNo
    ORDER BY
        CadastalMapNo
```